# npm outdated does not respect caret notation of package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

Using a **package.json** file with the following

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-dev-update": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-jasmine-node-new": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "^0.1.5",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-npm-install": "^0.1.0"
}
```

I get an `npm outdated` output that looks like

[image: npm outdated output]

Why is **Wanted** not 0.11.0? Doesn't `"grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0"` mean any version greater than or equal to 0.10.0 but less than 1.0.0 (`>= 0.10.0 && < 1.0.0`)? Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/1370556) as reference.

I'm using node v0.12.0 and npm v2.5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you currently have installed version `0.10.0` and it matches your version requirements. `npm` doesn't look for the newest versions if you have one that already fulfills the requirements.

You can execute `npm update` to update them to the latest version possible.