# npm install to get dependency with tag version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nexus, sonatype

**TL;DR:**

My project has dependency of `"dep": "snapshot"` where 'snapshot' is a tag. Running `npm install` does not fetch new version of "dep".

**Full story:**

So just recently I started with a JS project, and... to make a long story short i setup my own private repo via a locally installed Nexus.
Let's call my project `myProj1`.

I added the Nexus registry in my `.npmrc` like so:

`registry=http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/`

All is fine, I try and release snapshot versions before i release any production ready code.
This includes running `npm-snapshot X` where X is my snapshot number. (It's basically a plugin that changes the `package.json` version tag to something like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.24` (if X = 24)

I then run

`npm publish --tag=snapshot --registry=http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/npm-internal`

and it pushes the code to my Nexus, and all seems fine. The tag "snapshot" in my nexus registry is updated to the recently published version. (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.24)

I then have another project which has a dependency on the above module in it's `package.json` specified as such:

```
"dependencies": {
    "myProj1": "snapshot"
}
```

So I run `npm install` in the project root, and lo' and behold, the dependency get's downloaded perfectly, everything is awesome!

**Now here comes my issue:**

I then decide to update some stuff in `myProj1`, making me release another snapshot version with the same command above. (causing the newly published artifact to be versioned `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.25`) My Nexus is awesome and publishes the new dependency like it should, also updating the dist-tag "snapshot" to the newly built version.

**HOWEVER**, when i run `npm install` from my other project, believing I should be getting a newer version of `myProj1`, nothing happens. **It doesn't fetch the newer snapshot version. Why's that?**

Have I misunderstood having a dependency on a dist-tag? Can I do this some other way?

Regards

Comment: Unless things have changed recently, it could be that npm still doesn't handle snapshot versions: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2iobbs/how_do_you_handle_private_snapshot_builds_with_npm/

Comment: I know it doesn't. That's why I'm abusing the "pre-release" numbers. However i tag every "pre-release" but my project doesn't want to download the new "pre-releases"

Comment: @r0hitsharma I thought by adding the dependency by pointing to a "tag" that it'd do automatic updates when a new version on the same "tag" got released. But I guess not?

Comment: exactly, there's no new release in npm's eyes.

Comment: @r0hitsharma But there is! my npm registry updates the tag to point to a newer version. That must mean theres a new release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm outdated does not respect caret notation of package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636506/npm-outdated-does-not-respect-caret-notation-of-package-json)

Comment: Meeting the exact situation as you. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yep, same problem, after first pull, npm doesn't pull any newer versions, even when going from 1.0.2 to 1.0.3, etc.